# Problem in installing package through internet

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I have tried to install packages from `MiKtex2.9`-- `maintenance(admin)`-- `Miktex package manager(admin)` but I got an error message:

`no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

I tried to connect through `repository` -- `change package repository` -- `through internet`, It asked to select a proxy server, still I got an error as shown in the image. please give me a solution..  I am unable to write a single document. please help me. I'm a window user.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please try to use the package manager (without admin). You could do a *Repsotory* - *Synchronize* first but you do not seem to get any connection yet. Please go to *Repository* - *Change Package Repository...*, select the "Packages shall be installed from the internet" and check that the "Connection Settings..." are having the Proxy Server disabled. Then press *next*. If there are no repositories appearing, you have a faulty connection to the internet or your MiKTeX installation god broken.

Comment: Does your proxy allow the connexion?

Comment: Do you (should you) actually use a proxy. If you don't normally access the internet via a proxy there should be no need to specify one when making MikTeX updates. (The first error could have been because there was an update in the MikTeX repository going on - that of course is just a shot in the dark.)